# Groupby and count only specific values

Tags: python, pandas, count, group-by

I am currently working with a database in python and I am using pandas. My current database looks something like this:

```
Name      Approved
Google    true
Facebook  true
Apple     false
Trulia    true
Google    false
Trulia    true
```

I want to count only the 'true's for each company. So my out will look something like this:

```
Name    Approved
Google     1
Facebook   1
Apple      0
Trulia     2
```

This is my current code:

```
data.groupby(['Name'])[['Approved']].count()
```

which gets me this:

```
Name    Approved
Google     2
Facebook   1
Apple      1
Trulia     2
```

How can I alter this code to only count 'true's for each company? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load actual `True` `False` objects in your column, they are equivalent to 0 and 1 so just sum it:

```
df.groupby(['Name'])[['Approved']].sum().astype('int')
Out[144]: 
          Approved
Name              
Apple            0
Facebook         1
Google           1
Trulia           2
```

Comment: And for this example, `[['Approved']]` isn't needed of course (but I see why you included it) :)